# How to convert CSV data to paring array data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm trying to convert CSV data into paring array data, but I'm totally new to javascript, and I don't know how to do it now. Does any one have some idea? 
Thanks in advance!

CSV data:

```
year,USA,EU,UK,China,India
2003,10882,10970,1795,1575,599
2002,10383,9040,1564,1434,510
2001,10020,8303,1430,1345,479
2000,9762,8234,1438,1252,457
1999,9213,8901,1460,1158,447
1998,8720,8889,1423,1148,414
```

Object array data:

```
[{
  label: "USA",
  data: [[2003, 10882],
   [2002, 10383],
   [2001, 10020],
   [2000, 9762],
   [1999, 9213],
   [1998, 8720]]
 },

 {
  label: "EU",
  data: [[2003, 10970],
   [2002, 9040],
   [2001, 8303],
   [2000, 8234],
   [1999, 8901],
   [1998, 8889]]
 },

 {
  label: "UK",
  data: [[2003, 1795],
   [2002, 1564],
   [2001, 1430],
   [2000, 1438],
   [1999, 1460],
   [1998, 1423]]
 },

 {
  label: "China",
  data: [[2003, 1575],
   [2002, 1434],
   [2001, 1345],
   [2000, 1252],
   [1999, 1158],
   [1998, 1148]]
 },

 {
  label: "India",
  data: [[2003, 599],
   [2002, 510],
   [2001, 479],
   [2000, 457],
   [1999, 447],
   [1998, 414]]
 }]
```

Comment: Does it need to be Javascript? Can you use a server side language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your lines using `.split("\n")` function, with it you'll get this array

```
['year,USA,EU,UK,China,India',
'2003,10882,10970,1795,1575,599',
'2002,10383,9040,1564,1434,510',
'2001,10020,8303,1430,1345,479',
'2000,9762,8234,1438,1252,457',
'1999,9213,8901,1460,1158,447',
'1998,8720,8889,1423,1148,414']
```

Now you iterate this array `.split` again at `,`. You should get this after doing it:

```
[
    ['year','USA','EU','UK','China','India'],
    ['2003','10882','10970','1795','1575','599'],
    ['2002','10383','9040','1564','1434','510'],
    ['2001','10020','8303','1430','1345','479'],
    ['2000','9762','8234','1438','1252','457'],
    ['1999','9213','8901','1460','1158','447'],
    ['1998','8720','8889','1423','1148','414']
]
```

Now all you have to do is to iterate over this in a two level nested for loop, and build the object you want out of it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you give me an example showing how to do it generally?

Comment: You're welcome :) Try to give it a shot using the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function, and test the two nested loop things, if something fails or you couldn't do, you can ask about it.